# Image reconstruction from a sinogram via SVD, in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, svd, matrix-inverse

I've been tasked with reconstructing a 256x256 image from a 367x180 sinogram in MATLAB, using SVD.

I ran the SVD no problem using [U,S,V] = svd(true_sinogram);

This produces U (367 x 367), S (367 x 180), and V (180 x 180). My issue is that I'm not sure how to reconstruct the original image (not the sinogram) from this.

I've attempted the pseudo-inverse by A = V.*S_recip.*U';, where U' is the transpose of U and S_recip is the reciprocal of S, but I'm getting a "Matrix dimensions must agree" error.

Simple multiplcation of the original elements just results in the original true sinogram, which I can only back-project. Truncating the matrices to 180x180 also doesn't work.

Has anyone got any ideas? I feel I'm missing something obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not mere reciprocals of S but instead its transpose should be used to find pseudoinverse.

For example, if `A=U*S*V'` then the pseudoinverse of `A` would be equal to `V*S_recip'*U'`, where `S_recip'` is the transpose of `S_recip`, and would have its size as 180 x 367.